# Extract text from cell and define as string in vba

Tags: string, vba, excel, if-statement

I am hoping to pull text from a cell in my active sheet, define that information as a string and pass it through this If, ElseIf, Else loop. The issue I'm facing is that even though the text I pull contains "dw" the output is always "Not Found".

Its strange because I use message box to see if ss is actually getting defined correctly and it does so I don't think my issue is with pulling the text or defining the string.

(It may not be necessary information but lrow changes because the code below is a part of a larger loop)

```
Dim ss As String
Dim iRow As Long

iRow = Cells.find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
lRow = iRow

ss = Cells(lRow, 5).Text
'the message box below shows me that ss is pulling the info from the sheet that I'm looking for
'msgbox (ss)

If InStr(ss, "dw") > 0 Then
   Cells(lRow, 18).Formula = "=MID(E12,SEARCH(""dw""," & Chr(34) & ss & Chr(34) & "),6)"

ElseIf InStr(ss, "lex") > 0 Then
   Cells(lRow, 18).Formula = "=MID(E12,SEARCH(""lex""," & Chr(34) & ss & Chr(34) & "),7)"

ElseIf InStr(ss, "tex") > 0 Then
   Cells(lRow, 18).Formula = "=MID(E12,SEARCH(""tex""," & Chr(34) & ss & Chr(34) & "),7)"

ElseIf InStr(ss, "qex") > 0 Then
   Cells(lRow, 18).Formula = "=MID(E12,SEARCH(""qex""," & Chr(34) & ss & Chr(34) & "),7)"

ElseIf InStr(ss, "qnxr") > 0 Then
   Cells(lRow, 18).Formula = "=MID(E12,SEARCH(""qnxr""," & Chr(34) & ss & Chr(34) & "),8)"

Else
   Cells(lRow, 18).Value = "Not Found"
End If
```

Comment: Try `If InStr(1, ss, "dw", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then` and make the same change to the rest of your InStr statements

Comment: Alternately, instead of using any InStr statements, just use this single formula: `"=IFERROR(LOOKUP(REPT(""z"",255),MID(E" & lRow & ",SEARCH({""dw"",""lex"",""tex"",""qex"",""qnxr""},E" & lRow & "),{6,7,7,7,8})),""Not Found"")"`

Comment: Or use the formula directly in the cell: `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(REPT("z",255),MID(E2,SEARCH({"dw","lex","tex","qex","qnxr"},E2),{6,7,7,7,8})),"Not Found")`

Comment: Your first answer worked great! thank you!

Comment: @tigeravatar I like your alternate solutions. What does the rept(""z"",255) do though?

Comment: It creates a 255 string that is just the letter z over and over.  This is used by the Lookup function to return the match that is less than that value ignoring errors.